# JS prototype inheritance confusing

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Actual code.

```js
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

function Rabbit(speed) {
  Animal.call(this, 'Rabbit');
  this.speed = speed;
}

Rabbit.prototype = Animal;
var rabbit = new Rabbit(50);
console.log(rabbit.name, rabbit.speed);
```

I expected to have console output:
**Rabbit 50**

But I have
**Animal 50**

Can anybody explain why **Animal** function doesn't rewrite its **name** property?

Comment: Where did you get this `Rabbit.prototype = Animal; ` part from? It should be `Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)`

Comment: I just played with code and tried this assignment. Also, I debugged this in chrome and first, Rabbit called, then Animal function and it had already assigned 'name' as 'Animal', but 'undefined' if I didn't set the prototype for Rabbit. That was the confusing point I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Animal` just a function

'function' object has a property 'name'

for example

```
function app(){
 console.log("hello")
}
console.log(app.name) // "app"


function Animal(name){
 this.name = name;
}
console.log(Animal.name) // "Animal"
```

so Animal object has a property 'name', function object also has a property 'name'

you can try this

```js
function Animal(name) {
  this.notname = name; //do not use "name" as a property name
}

function Rabbit(speed) {
  Animal.call(this, 'Rabbit');
  this.speed = speed;
}

Rabbit.prototype = Animal;
var rabbit = new Rabbit(50);
console.log(rabbit.notname, rabbit.speed);
```

or

```js
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

function Rabbit(speed) {
  Animal.call(this, 'Rabbit');
  this.speed = speed;
}

Rabbit.prototype = new Animal(); 
//you should point the Rabbit.prototype to a Animal object,not a function

var rabbit = new Rabbit(50);
console.log(rabbit.name, rabbit.speed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), you should end up with something like:

```js
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name
}

function Rabbit(speed) {
  Animal.call(this, 'Rabbit')
  this.speed = speed
}

Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)
// If you don't set this line, `new Rabbit` would call `Animal` constructor
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit
var rabbit = new Rabbit(50)
console.log(rabbit.name, rabbit.speed)
```